# How can i show and keep a variable when redirecting back and forth from an html to a jsp page and a jsp page to an html?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am making a guess the number application using a servlet, when i enter a number and press the "guess button" it sends me to a jsp page and tells me if the number is too low, too high or if i guessed it correctly. I have a link in my jsp page that take me back to the html page to guess again.

My question is that, how do i keep my generated number that i need to guess when going back an forth from the html page to my jsp page so i can keep guessing that same number?? For example if the number i need to guess is 50 and i press the "guess button" and it takes to me to the jsp, no matter what the result is, how do i keep that number until i close the web page? (NOTE: when i use `<%= session.getAttribute("numero") %>` i get NULL )

This my code:

```
package numero;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Eddy
 */

@WebServlet(name = "Controlador", urlPatterns = {"/Adivina"})
public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    Generador generar;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");       

        String compartir = "compartir";
        request.setAttribute("compartirID", compartir); // add to request
        request.getSession().setAttribute("compartirID", compartir); // add to session
        this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().setAttribute("compartirID", compartir); // add to application context
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Adivina").forward(request, response);
    }//http se contituye por transacciones

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //recupera información enviada por el cliente
        String numero = request.getParameter("numero");
        double valor = Double.parseDouble(numero);

        //envía al modelo para procesamiento
        String[] num = generar.numero(valor);

        //redirecciona a la vista
        request.setAttribute("resultado", num);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/mostrar.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }

}
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adivina el Numero</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Adivina el Numero!</h1>
        <h2>Ingrese un numero del 1 al 100</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="Adivina">
            Ingrese el numero: <input type="text" name="numero"/></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Adivina"/></br>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.text.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adivinar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Bienvenido</h3>
        <%= session.getAttribute("numero") %>
        <table>   
            <% 
                String[] resultado = (String[])request.getAttribute("resultado");
                for(String str : resultado) { 
            %>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
                    <%= str %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% 
                }
            %>
        </table>
        <a href="adivina.html">Regresar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my number generating class:

```
package numero;

/**
 *
 * @author Eddy
 */

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class Generador {

    public String[] numero(double numero) {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        x = (Math.random() * 100)+1;
        x = Math.floor(x);

        /*y = (Math.random() * x)+1;
        y = Math.floor(y);

        x+=x;

        System.out.println("x=" + x);
        System.out.println("y=" + y);*/

        if(numero>=1 && numero<=100)
        {       
            if(numero>x)
            {
                return new String[] {"Muy Alto"};
            }
            else if(numero<x)
            {    
                return new String[] {"Muy Bajo"};
            }
            else if(numero==x)
            {
                return new String[] {"Adivinó"};
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new String[] {"Ingrese un numero dentro del rango"};
        }    
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is : 
you generate a new number when you want to compare it with the input of the user 
the solution is to separate the geneated number and put it into an attribute in the Controlador class  like this :

```
public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {
private double x;
...
}
```

and add a procedure in the servlet that generate a number 
public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {

```
public void generate(){
 x = 0;

        x = (Math.random() * 100)+1;
        x = Math.floor(x);

 }
```

then set the generated value in the session

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("Val",generated_Value);
```

and then pass two attribute in the function

```
generar.numero(valor,generated_Value);
```

when you want to return to the page where the user gess this must be a jsp page (Rather than html) 
where you save the generated value in a hidden input

finally try this code  :

```
 public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {

    private double x;

        @EJB
        Generador generar;


        public void generate(){
         x = 0;

                x = (Math.random() * 100)+1;
                x = Math.floor(x);

         }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {


        }

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            String generatedVal = request.getParameter("genVAL");
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(generatedVal); 
            if(generatedVal==null){
             generate();

             d=x;
            }


            String numero = request.getParameter("numero");
            double valor = Double.parseDouble(numero);

            //envía al modelo para procesamiento
            String num = generar.numero(valor,d);

            //redirecciona a la vista
            request.getSession().setAttribute("Val",d); 
            request.setAttribute("resultado", num);
            request.setAttribute("numero", numero);

request.getRequestDispatcher("/mostrar.jsp").forward(request,response);
        }

    }
```

after this change the html to jsp and put this in the form :

```
<form method="POST" action="Adivina">
            Ingrese el numero: <input type="text" name="numero"/></br>
            <input type="hidden" name="genVAL" value="${Val}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Adivina"/></br>

        </form>
```

and change the function numero to  numero(double numero,double x)

```
@Stateless
public class Generador {

    public String numero(double numero,double x) {


        if(numero>=1 && numero<=100)
        {       
            if(numero>x)
            {
                return "Muy Alto";
            }
            else if(numero<x)
            {    
                return "Muy Bajo";
            }
            else if(numero==x)
            {
                return "Adivinó";
            }

        } else
        {
            return "Ingrese un numero dentro del rango";
        }    

    }
}
```

and the second jsp page :

```
<%@page import="java.text.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adivinar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Bienvenido</h3>
        ${numero}
        <table>   

            <tr>
                <td bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
                    ${resultado}
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <a href="adivina.html">Regresar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting an empty string somewhere, i think on the controlador.java part

Comment: I don't understand why you are using a Stateless do it with a simple java class and instanciate it in the servlet